# Ubuntu don't recognizes system available space

Tags: virtualbox, storage

**I created a virtual disk (with virtual box) initially with 10 gb of storage. I've installed ubuntu on it.** It started showing warnings that storage was low so i changed the virtual disk capacity to 25 gb. But when i run ubuntu it keeps showing the same warnings, it seems like ubuntu don't recognize the new available space.

How can e solve this?

---

After running this command:

```
lsblk -o name,size,type,fstype,mountpoint
```

I got this:

```
NAME     SIZE TYPE FSTYPE   MOUNTPOINT
loop0    4.9M loop squashfs /snap/canonical-livepatch/41
loop1   29.5M loop squashfs /snap/sublime-text/18
loop2   86.6M loop squashfs /snap/core/4486
loop3  139.4M loop squashfs /snap/chromium/343
loop4   86.6M loop squashfs /snap/core/4650
loop5  139.8M loop squashfs /snap/chromium/353
sda       25G disk          
├─sda1     1M part          
└─sda2    10G part ext4     /
sr0     55.3M rom  iso9660  /media/dk/VBox_GAs_5.2.12
```

---

```
sudo parted /dev/sda resizepart 2 -1s
[sudo] password for dk: 
parted: invalid option -- '1'
Usage: parted [-hlmsv] [-a<align>] [DEVICE [COMMAND [PARAMETERS]]...]
dk@dkserver:/opt$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2
resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
The filesystem is already 2620672 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

(It didn't worked)

---

Result 3:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda -- resizepart 2 -1s
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to
use all of the space (an extra 31457280 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
parted: invalid token: 2                                                  
Fix/Ignore? y                                                             
parted: invalid token: y
Fix/Ignore? f                                                             
Partition number?
```

**Wich partition number should i put?**

---

What value should i put? 25 gb (or is it in megabytes?) or should i give less (counting with other systems/partitions space )?

```
sudo parted /dev/sda                                    
[sudo] password for dk: 
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) help                                                             
  align-check TYPE N                        check partition N for TYPE(min|opt) alignment
  help [COMMAND]                           print general help, or help on COMMAND
  mklabel,mktable LABEL-TYPE               create a new disklabel (partition table)
  mkpart PART-TYPE [FS-TYPE] START END     make a partition
  name NUMBER NAME                         name partition NUMBER as NAME
  print [devices|free|list,all|NUMBER]     display the partition table, available devices, free
        space, all found partitions, or a particular partition
  quit                                     exit program
  rescue START END                         rescue a lost partition near START and END
  resizepart NUMBER END                    resize partition NUMBER
  rm NUMBER                                delete partition NUMBER
  select DEVICE                            choose the device to edit
  disk_set FLAG STATE                      change the FLAG on selected device
  disk_toggle [FLAG]                       toggle the state of FLAG on selected device
  set NUMBER FLAG STATE                    change the FLAG on partition NUMBER
  toggle [NUMBER [FLAG]]                   toggle the state of FLAG on partition NUMBER
  unit UNIT                                set the default unit to UNIT
  version                                  display the version number and copyright information
        of GNU Parted
(parted) resizepart 2
Warning: Partition /dev/sda2 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
Yes/No? y                                                                 
End?  [10.7GB]?
```

---

**Result 4:**

```
lsblk -o name,size,type,fstype,mountpoint
NAME     SIZE TYPE FSTYPE   MOUNTPOINT
loop0    4.9M loop squashfs /snap/canonical-livepatch/41
loop1   86.6M loop squashfs /snap/core/4650
loop2  139.8M loop squashfs /snap/chromium/353
loop3   86.6M loop squashfs /snap/core/4486
loop4   29.5M loop squashfs /snap/sublime-text/18
loop5  139.4M loop squashfs /snap/chromium/343
sda       25G disk          
├─sda1     1M part          
└─sda2    25G part ext4     /
sr0     55.3M rom  iso9660  /media/dk/VBox_GAs_5.2.12
dk@dkserver:~$ df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       9.8G  9.1G  230M  98% /
```

Comment: You probably need to extend a partition too.

Comment: Please edit the question and include the results displayed by `lsblk -o name,size,type,fstype,mountpoint`.

Comment: @AlexP i've please check the update

Comment: Right. You need to extend `/dev/sda2` to the end of the disk (`sudo parted /dev/sda resizepart 2 -1s`)  and then resize the filesystem (`sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2`).

Comment: @AlexP This looks like a good answer.

Comment: it didn't worked, please see my edit @AlexP

Comment: Sorry, forgot `--`; the correct form is `sudo parted /dev/sda -- resizepart 2 -1s`. (The `--` tells `parted` that no more options follow.)

Comment: It's asking for partition number, it's 2 rigth? @AlexP

Comment: It shouldn't ask for anything -- I have tested the command. If it asks for something then please copy and post the command and question.

Comment: its posted , please check @AlexP

Comment: Ah, I see, you formatted the disk using GPT. Then run `sudo parted /dev/sda2` and extend the partition number `2` manually.

Comment: it's asking for one more thing (see edit please) @AlexP

Comment: Say `-34s`. (This means 34 sectors before the end of the disk; since you formatted the disk with GPT you must leave room at the end for the second copy of the GPT.)

Comment: Now it shows 25G for the partition 2, i think its done. But appeared this: "Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab."  how i do this? @AlexP

Comment: You don't need to update anything. Resize the filesystem with `resize2fs`, then reboot the VM and check that the filesystem has been extended.

Comment: So why Disk Usage Analyser keeps showing warnings and still showing the old disk space? How i update it to the new disk space? @AlexP

Comment: Do the `lsblk` again, please, and `df -h /`.

Comment: @AlexP please see my update (result 4)

Comment: Then do the `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extend the partition `/dev/sda2` to cover the newly added space, and then you need to resize the filesystem to fill the partition.

1. Extend `/dev/sda2` to the end of the disk.

   If the disk uses the MBR partition scheme then it's easy:

   ```
   sudo parted /dev/sda -- resizepart 2 -1s
   ```

   If the disk uses the GPT partition scheme, then run

   ```
   sudo parted /dev/sda
   ```

   and extend partition number `2` manually.
2. Resize the filesystem to fill the partition:

   ```
   sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2
   ```

Comment: sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
If the output of the above command shows like this,then you have MBR disk,

Partition table scan:
MBR: MBR only
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: not present
If the output shows like this then you have GPT disk,

Partition table scan:
MBR: protective
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: present

Comment: parted /dev/sda -- resizepart 2 -1s
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

root@ubuntu:/home/qgb# resize2fs /dev/sda2                                
resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
open: No such device or address while opening /dev/sda2