# How can I add the new space to a volume group after resizing partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, fstab, lvm

This was the output of `lsblk` before running parted:

```
sda                     8:0    0    90G  0 disk 
└─sda1                  8:1    0    40G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:0    0    39G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:1    0   976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

After adding more space to my virtual machine disk I ran the following commands to reflect the new space in the OS:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda
resizepart 1 
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
quit
```

Then o got this message:

```
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

Now the output of `lsblk` is:

```
sda                     8:0    0    90G  0 disk 
└─sda1                  8:1    0    90G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:0    0    39G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:1    0   976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

**But the system is still showing 42GB instead of new 90GB disk size, I think I need to do something to add the storage in ubuntu--vg-root ...**

Is it because I need to update /etc/fstab? If so, how? If not then which commands should I run?

Comment: i followed a tutorial...i have not knowledge about this, how can i solve it?

Comment: I've followed this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043928/ubuntu-dont-recognizes-system-available-space?noredirect=1#comment1701749_1043928

Comment: Im going to install KDE Volume and Partition Manager

Comment: I need help, i cant extend the disk size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your system uses [Logical Volume Management (LVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management). In this setup, a partition does not directly host a filesystem but an LVM *physical volume*. The filesystem is hosted by an LVM *logical volume* which is contained on one or more physical volumes.

I recreated your situation in a VM. Just doing `resizepart` using `parted` does not extend the physical volume:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0   90G  0 disk 
└─sda1                  8:1    0   90G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root   252:0    0   39G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 252:1    0  976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]

$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree 
  /dev/sda1  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  40,00g 44,00m
```

So you need to [extend the physical volume](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pvresize):

```
sudo pvresize /dev/sda1
```

The result can be checked using [`pvs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pvs):

```
$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree 
  /dev/sda1  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  90,00g 50,04g
```

Then [resize the logical volume](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lvresize). Use `-r` to automatically resize the contained filesystem. After the prefix `/dev/mapper/`, specify the logical volume name shown by `lsblk` below `sda1`:

```
sudo lvresize -r -l+100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

Both these operations can be done even when booted from the resized drive, you don’t need to boot a live CD.

The result:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0   90G  0 disk 
└─sda1                  8:1    0   90G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root   252:0    0   89G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 252:1    0  976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the right solution (and question) that I was looking for.